# can I consume a method in Silverlight of WCF which returns datatable?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to create custom datatable in WCF method and want to return. Is it possible? If not tell me optional way to use datatable in silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

At least when I last looked (which was around the time of Silverlight 3), `DataTable` (actually, IIRC, the entire `System.Data` namespace) was not included in Silverlight. The workaround was to convert the data into a `List<T>` representation on the WCF (server) side, then let the server and client side share the implementation of the type `T`. That allows them to share sets of data.

Not sure if this has changed in Silverlight 4.